# Convert latin1 gibberish characters to UTF-8 Hebrew characters using iconv function

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

I have database that contain Hebrew characters that some of them are stored and encoded as `latin1`, the character shown as gibberish but just in database they shown like that, when I open the website the Hebrew characters appear as they need to be.

I need to convert the database and move it to work with a new system using converter, the convert supposed to convert all the entries in database to `utf-8` using `iconv` function but instead I receive gibberish characters in website after the conversion.

There is a way using `iconv` function to convert gibberish characters to Hebrew characters? Like in this way:

```
$hebrew = array("א", "ב", "ג", "ד", "ה", "ו", "ז", "ח", "ט", "י", "כ", "ל", "מ", "נ", "ס", "ע", "פ", "צ", "ק", "ר", "ש", "ת", "ך", "ם", "ן", "ף", "ץ");
$gibberish = array("à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ë", "ì", "î", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ô", "ö", "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "ê", "í", "ï", "ó", "õ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's str_replace function.

```
$hebrew = array("א", "ב", "ג", "ד", "ה", "ו", "ז", "ח", "ט", "י", "כ", "ל", "מ", "נ", "ס", "ע", "פ", "צ", "ק", "ר", "ש", "ת", "ך", "ם", "ן", "ף", "ץ");
$gibberish = array("à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ë", "ì", "î", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ô", "ö", "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "ê", "í", "ï", "ó", "õ");
$str = str_replace( $gibberish, $hebrew, 'àåâðãä' );
```